# Loading python pickled object in C

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I know pickles can be easily loaded into python using

```
import pickle
p = pickle.load(open("file.pkl"))
```

I was wondering how to load the same pickle file in pyx/C code in python? I couldn't find the method to directly load it.

Perhaps a solution would be to load in python and pass reference to object in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer would be to just compile your code with Cython. Everything there will be done automatically.

In context of the Python C API, you could easily replicate this code with something like:

```
PyObject *file = NULL, *p = NULL;
PyObject *pickle = PyImport_ImportModule("pickle"); // import module
if (!pickle) goto error;
file = PyFile_FromString("file.pkl", "r"); // open("file.pkl")
if (!pickle) goto error;
p = PyObject_CallMethod(pickle, "load", "O", file); // pickle.load(file)
error:
Py_XDECREF(pickle);
Py_XDECREF(file);
```

This is done for Python 2, while for Python 3 `open("file.pkl")` needs to be implemented by using the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io) module.