# How to load a pickled python list using pybind11 in C++

Tags: c++, pybind11

I have some pickled objects stored in a redis cache, and a C++ process needs to access them. Are there any facilities in pybind11 that lets me go from the pickled byte array to an std::vector?

I did find a way to do it in C using the python C library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768773/loading-python-pickled-object-in-c), which could serve as a starting point. But I would still need to use the binding library to convert it to an std::vector.

Comment: Did you read https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html  ? Examples should suffice your needs.

Comment: Embedding the interpreter is an interesting approach that could work. This is a minimalist executable that need to be as absolutely lean as possible, so I am hesitant to do it in this context and would prefer an API to do it directly. Looks like I ultimately need to switch to JSON serialization instead of pickling.

Comment: Could be. It's hard to advise with a limited information about your use case. Probably the simplest solution would be to mock example you linked in question with pybind utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Pybind11 comes with pickle support, check it out in their [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#pickling-support).

Comment: The question is not about making exposed C++ objects pickleable, but rather reading existing pickles from C++.

Comment: Hi, are any methods to automatical enable all C++ objects to be pickleable?